# Set Binding of DataGridTextColumn's TextBlock

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I'm trying to change the binding for the "Text" property for a TextBox inside of a DataGrid. Consider the following code:

```
<DataGrid Name="CoreView837" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="366" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="792"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectionUnit="Cell" SelectionMode="Extended" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="ClaimNumber"  Header="Claim Number" Width="350" Binding="{Binding ClaimNumber}">

    </DataGridTextColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name ="Parent837" Header="837 Segment" Width="300" ClipboardContentBinding="{Binding SegmentText}">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ScrollViewer MaxHeight="100">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="Segment837" Text="{Binding SegmentText}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Errors" Width="350" ClipboardContentBinding="{Binding ErrorText}">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ScrollViewer MaxHeight="100">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ErrorText}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

I want to change the binding of the TextBlock "Segment837" in the code behind to a new binding, like below:

```
Segment837.Binding = new Binding("Value");
```

However, it seems that I can't change the Text binding of the TextBlock directly. It seems I can only select "Parent837."

Can anyone suggest to me how to change the binding either directly or even a better way? Right now I have the binding set for when a text file's broken segments are successfully loaded, but I wanted to change the binding of the TextBlock for instance in the case that it fails and I want to return alternative data.

Comment: A `TextBlock` doesn't have a property named `Binding`, so `Segment837.Binding` should not even compile. Are you trying to change the `DataContext`? Or the Binding of `Segment837.Text`? Perhaps you're looking for [FallbackValue or TargetNullValue](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/41e70f/fallbackvalue-in-wpf/)?

Comment: I'm trying to change the Binding of Segment837.Text

Comment: If [FallbackValue or TargetNullValue](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/41e70f/fallbackvalue-in-wpf/) aren't what you're looking for, maybe you want to look at [MultiBinding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.multibinding(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: How would the FallbackValue approach be used?

Comment: My two previous comments had a link for [FallbackValue and TargetNullValue](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/41e70f/fallbackvalue-in-wpf/) which includes code snippets, here it is again :https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/41e70f/fallbackvalue-in-wpf/

Comment: My bad for not opening those links... I think that is a good approach to what I'm trying to do here. I'll give that a go next time I'm in front of this. Thanks!

Comment: You don't have access to `Segment837` variable in code behind because it is inside a `Template`, meaning your `TextBlock` will be recreated multiple times (once for every row), so your code behind cannot access a single instance of this `TextBlock` by using the name.

Comment: So for MultiBinding, I would set the bindings property to, say, the values of a dictionary I created for instance? (I've set the bindings of the first text column to be the key of the said dictionary)